# Excel 2013 VBA Macro Needed for Highlighting with Multiple Conditionals

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, vba

I need help writing an Excel macro that does quite a few things. My contribution was the macro to get the data into this format, but I'm stuck on highlighting, and don't even have the slightest idea how to proceed. Sorry this is super long, and thanks a bunch in advance! :D

The problem I'm having is that if there are duplicate names in column A, I need the total of all of the totals in column D for that end user to be used to find the highlighting color.

The only ones receiving the highlighting will say "#N/A" in column E. If there are multiple companies but one doesn't say "#N/A" in Column E, then only the ones that say "#N/A" would be included in the highlighting/adding of totals…

1. If column A has more than one of the same company name, AND the totals in Column D for all of the same company add up to be greater than 0, AND the Order Number in Column C for ALL of the same company begins with a "5" (I have been using =LEFT($C1,1)+0=5), AND Column E = "#N/A", THEN highlight A:E in yellow.
2. If Column A has more than one of the same company name, AND the totals in Column D for all of the same company add up to be greater than 0, BUT not all Order Numbers in Column C begin with a "5," AND Column E = "#N/A", THEN the cells for A:E for the Order number with a "5" are blue (Color 15773696), AND the cells for A:E for the Order Numbers not beginning with a "5" are red.
3. If Column A has more than one of the same company name, AND the totals in Column D for all of the same company add up to be 0, AND Column E = "#N/A", THEN highlight cells A:E in red.
4. If Column A has more than one of the same company name, AND the totals in Column D for all of the same company add up to be < 0, AND Column E = "#N/A", THEN highlight cells A:E for all company lines in orange (Color 49407).
5. If Column A has only one company name, AND the Order Number in Column C begins with a "5," AND the total in Column D is > 0, AND Column E = "#N/A", THEN highlight cells A:E for the company name in blue (Color 15773696).
6. If Column A has only one company name, AND the total in Column D is < 0, AND Column E = "#N/A", THEN highlight cells A:E for the company name in orange (Color 49407).
7. If Column A has only one company name, AND the Order Number in Column C does not begin with a "5," AND the total in Column D is >= 0, THEN highlight cells A:E for the company name in red.
8. If the line is blue, insert the text "Booking DER?" into Column F.

Thanks soooooo much for your help! :) I would post an example picture, but it won't let me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options one is to use conditional formatting it's easier but takes more time in my opinion

You can also use private methods to change the cells format when their values changes, to do so you need to create a code inside the worksheet on the VBA, select the worksheet you want to use the code with on the list on the left top  select "View Code" that's where you must write the code

But be carefull since you're handling with errors such as "#N/A" because if you do things such as

`If Range("C2").value = "#N/A" then` ...

it won't work, because "#N/A" is not the cell value it's a error indicator, so you must use something like this:

`If worksheetfunciton.IfError(Range("C2"),"Error") = "Error" then` ...

In this example if the cells on the determined range has their values changed the coe will display a message telling you that this cell has changed, all you have to do is change the range according to your desire and change the line: `MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."` for your conditions, this should work, one method to higlight the cell can be the `cells().Interior.ColorIndex = "color number"`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:C10")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been 
        ' changed.
        ' Place your code here.
        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."

    End If
End Sub
```